# adb push and mount problems

Tags: adb, mount, file-permissions

I'm using Android 2.3.3 and I want to copy the iwconfig file to /system/xbin.
First I tried doing it with adb push using this:

`adb push iwconfig /system/xbin`

But in return I had: failed to copy 'iwconfig' to '/system/xbin/iwconfig': Permission denied

So I made my research and finally found this mount command that actually worked (most of them returned the usage: mount []... line)

`mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system`

But even with that I'm still having the "Permission denied" line.

I also tried
`mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system/xbin`

Buth it returned "Invalid Argument"

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are trying with an emulator, then you can first use 'adb remount' which remounts the system partition for read-write.  Also, see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android

Comment: First use mount command without any arguments. This will list all the mount points and its name.  Search for '/system' and it might have different mtdbblock#.  For instance, in my device it is '/dev/block/mtdblock1 /system yaffs2 rw,relatime 0 0'.  Hence I have to correct the mount statement to appropriate mtdbblock# number in order for the command to work.

Comment: I'm using a real device, I saw that question already, but it didn't helped, it accepts the mount command, but when I try to push the file, it still tells me that permissions are denied.

Comment: if your device is rooted, probably you can push the file to /mnt/sdcard and then on the device, either use a terminal emulator or file explorer (with root access) to move the files. That's what I did when I replaced two files in /system/bin.

Comment: @Narayanan, I did what you tell, I saw this:
/dev/block/mtdblock1 /system yaffs2 rw,relatime 0 0
So I tried:
mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock1 /system
But when i try to push the file, it stills tells me that permissions are denied.

Comment: I finally got to run iwconfig, what I did was copying to SD card and made a link with 
# ln -s /mnt/sdcard/iwconfig /system/xbin/iwconfig
I just have a problem now, I can't run it, because of the permissions, but when I do chmod 777 iwconfig it does not returns an error message and does not change permissions, how can I change a file permissions without chmod? or which is the correct way of using chmod in Android?

Comment: Is adbd running as root?  What happens when you issue the `adb root` command?  Also, try simply `mount -o remount,rw /system`.  If that fails, try `su` first.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure adbd is running as root:

`adb root`

If you get an error that says something like *"unable to run as root on production builds"* it means that you must always issue `su` command in the adb shell to gain superuser privileges.  You will need to enter the shell before any `mount` commands will work.  You will need to push the file to the SD Card, then mount /system partition as read-write, and then copy the file to the /xbin directory like so:

```
adb push [path-to-iwconfig] /sdcard/
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
cp /sdcard/iwconfig /system/xbin/
mount -o remount,ro /system
exit
exit
```

Comment: As you said, it returned "unable to run as root production builds", then mount -o remount,rw /system returns: usage: mount[-r][-w][-o options] [-t type] device directory. I solved this using: mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock1 /system. cp /sdcard/iwconfig /system/xbin/ returns: cp: not found

Comment: Try `busybox cp` instead.

Comment: Or use `cat` - that works quite well as a useful alternative `cat [source] > [destination]`

Comment: I have a rooted device, and get root access with SU command in shell, but when I want to cp a file to /system/lib/ , I get this: Read-only file system

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Did you mount /system partition for read/write access?

Comment: @Chahk It's work. I had to type 'su' command. Thanks.